# Pull an image from an XML file into HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Basically design a small electronic shop website,I'm putting product information within a table and I'd like to add the images within the table as well.Here is the JavaScript code that works for pulling the data into the table.

```
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("DELIVERY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
```

Everything shows within the table but the image, it just shows up as Null, here is the XML file

```
<ProductsTable>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>Corsair PC Full Tower</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$80</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/case.jpg"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>Asus Motherboard</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$129.99</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/mobo.jpg"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>16GB Vengeance RAM</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$44.99</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/ram.png"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>Corsair VS650w PSU</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$64.99</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/psu.png"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>Intel i7-7700 CPU</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$139.99</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/cpu.jpg"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <TITLE>Nvidia 1080 Graphics Card</TITLE>
    <DELIVERY>Free Delivery!</DELIVERY>
    <PRICE>$326.99</PRICE>
    <IMAGE><image href="images/gpu.png"/></IMAGE>
  </Product>
.
.
.
</ProductsTable>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
Pic of where I'm at https://gyazo.com/be6b82d3ee90776ece46e6d7d9db221f

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Try this: `x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].attributes[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<image>` tag has no content, so `nodeValue` is empty.

You need to get the `href` attribute & put it in an HTML `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of the image through `attributes` field.

Change this:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

To this:

```
x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].attributes[0].value
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it doesn't load any part of the table when I changed the code, the data that did appear isn't coming up/

Comment: I've change 
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Product"); to
var x = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Product");
Now the name of the image files pop up along with the rest of the table data

Comment: The error that was in the console before making the change was Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at myFunction (Store.html:40)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange (Store.html:26)

Comment: Hi yes I have used the last updated answer, do you think its an issue with the XML?